# Programa en c++ que lea un archivo .csv y haga operaciones con esa información

Tags: c++

Necesito hacer un programa que lea de un archivo `csv` una lista de `NITs` y total de compra y que haga los siguientes cálculos:

- Sumatoria NITs:
- Media NITs
- Min NITs
- Max NITs
- Count NITs

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void leer();

int main ()
{
  leer ();
  return 0;
}

void leer(){ 
    string nombre;
    ifstream infile("proye.csv");
    string line = "   "; //comillas vacias para guardar las lineas
    vector<string> datos_csv;
    //while para ir guardando los datos
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        stringstream strstr(line);
        string word="  ";//tambien para recorrer
        while(getline(strstr,word,';'))
        {
            //como le vamos ir agregando los datos
            datos_csv.push_back(word);
        }
    }

    //lo imprimire con un for
    for(int i=0; i<datos_csv.size();i++)
    {
        //.at para obtener el dato en este caso en la posicion i
        cout<<i<<".-  "<< datos_csv.at(i)<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"\nacumulado en nits: ";
}
```

```
nit                     fecha.          total
225137144,16/08/2017,2263.69
161994665,27/10/2017,163.76
557881681,11/12/2017,481.28
623029452,26/03/2017,313.39
887266478,22/11/2017,435.84
481274889,21/07/2017,50.83
 373633650,16/12/2017,1527.31
 272299473,03/05/2017,2904.89
 457951556,02/10/2017,723.23
```

Tengo varios de estos datos en un archivo CSV y hay muchos repetidos. Tengo problema en sumar cada uno de ellos por ejemplo tengo el nit: 225137144 con un valor de 2263.69 y luego tengo otra vez el mismo nit pero con otro valor. ¿Cómo podría hacer para que se sumen esos valores?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Comment: ¿Qué has probado hasta ahora para sumar los valores y obtener el resultado? Imagino que las matemáticas las conoces, ¿no? Es decir, que la media es el total entre el número de elementos, etc. No sé si tienes problemas contando el número de elementos o sumar cada uno de ellos.

Comment: `nit                  fecha  total`
`225137144,16/08/2017,2263.69`
`161994665,27/10/2017,163.76`
`557881681,11/12/2017,481.28`
`623029452,26/03/2017,313.39`
`887266478,22/11/2017,435.84`
`481274889,21/07/2017,50.83`
`373633650,16/12/2017,1527.31`
`272299473,03/05/2017,2904.89`
`457951556,02/10/2017,723.23`
tengo varios de estos datos en un archivo csv y hay muchos repetidos
tengo problema en sumar cada uno de ellos 
por ejemplo tengo el nit: 225137144 con un valor de 2263.69 y luego tengo otraz vez el mismo nit pero con otro valor  
como podria hacer para que se sumen esos valores

Comment: Es mejor que estos datos nuevos los agregues a tu pregunta [editándola en este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/338654/edit).

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Comment: Recuerda nombrar con un @ a la persona a la que hablas para que le llegue una notificación, en caso contrario sólo veremos tus avances si por pura casualidad volvemos a pasar por la pregunta y nos fijamos. Voy a redactar una respuesta con una implementación muy sencilla basada en una lista, sin complicarme la vida usando árboles o estructuras optimizadas.

Comment: @martin perdona tengo el mismo ejercicio pero siempre me tira la misma respuesta: Error al intentar abrir el archivo, ¿Qué podría estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pueden obtener todos los nits y la agregación de los totales almacenándolos en un `std::map`. Antes de agregar un valor nuevo lo buscamos y si existe lo sumamos al acumulado anterior.

En el código dejo comentarios de lo que hago en cada momento:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

/* Ahora la función devolverá los datos leídos y agregados */
std::map<long, double> leer();

int main ()
{
    /* Ahora puedo leer los datos y almacenarlos en algún sitio */
    std::map<long, double> datos = leer();
    /* Ahora iteramos por cada dato leído */
    for (std::map<long, double>::iterator i = datos.begin(); i != datos.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << "nit: " << i->first << ", suma total: " << i->second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

std::map<long, double> leer()
{ 
    std::ifstream infile("proye.csv");
    std::string line;
    /* Guardaré el acumulado en un map para acelerar la búsqueda */
    std::map<long, double> sumados;
    std::map<long, double>::iterator buscaSumados;

    /* Iteramos por cada línea en el archivo */
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        std::stringstream strstr(line);
        std::string word;
        /* Ontenemos el "nit" del primer elemento */
        getline(strstr, word, ',');
        long nit = std::stol(word);
        /* Y el total del tercero */
        getline(strstr, word, ',');
        getline(strstr, word, ',');
        double total = std::stod(word);
        /* Buscamos la existencia del mismo nit */
        buscaSumados = sumados.find(nit);
        if (buscaSumados == sumados.end()) {
            /* Si no existe el elemento lo creamos */
            sumados.insert(std::pair<long, double>(nit, total));
        } else {
            /* En caso contrario sumamos al valor anterior el actual */
            buscaSumados->second += total;
        }
    }
    return sumados;
}
```

---

Si necesitas leer igualmente todos los datos del CSV, existe una solución al problema usando un `std::vector` para almacenar cada elemento del CSV y usar el mismo `std::map` para la suma agregada.

Para hacerlo más legible he creado una clase que representa los valores de cada línea del CSV, pero es completamente prescindible si sólo quieres la suma y no te importa almacenar los datos de cada línea.

En el código dejo comentarios de lo que hago en cada momento:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

void leer();

/* Creo una clase para almacenar los datos fácilmente y mostrarlos en un ostream */
class Dato
{
public:
    long nit;
    std::string fecha;
    double total;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dato& obj);
};
/* Implemento el operador "<<" para facilitar su impresión */
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dato& objeto)
{
    os << "nit: " << objeto.nit << ", fecha: " << objeto.fecha << ", total: " << objeto.total;
}

int main()
{
  leer();
  return 0;
}

void leer()
{ 
    std::string nombre;
    std::ifstream infile("proye.csv");
    std::string line;

    /* Guardaré los datos en un vector de elementos */
    std::vector<Dato *> datos_csv;
    /* Guardaré el acumulado en un map para acelerar la búsqueda */
    std::map<long, double> sumados;
    std::map<long, double>::iterator buscaSumados;

    /* Iteramos por cada línea en el archivo */
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        std::stringstream strstr(line);
        std::string word;
        /* Creamos un nuevo elemento en el que guardaremos los datos */
        Dato *actual = new Dato();
        /* El separador del CSV es una coma, no un punto y coma */
        for (int indice = 0; getline(strstr, word, ','); indice++) {
            switch(indice) {
                case 0:
                    /* El primer índice lo guardamos en "nit" */
                    actual->nit = std::stol(word);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    /* El segundo elemento será la fecha, la guardo tal cual */
                    actual->fecha = word;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    /* Por último va el valor */
                    actual->total = std::stod(word);
                    break;
            }
        }
        /* Almacenamos la línea en los datos del CSV */
        datos_csv.push_back(actual);
        /* Cálculo de la suma: buscamos la existencia del mismo nit */
        buscaSumados = sumados.find(actual->nit);
        if (buscaSumados == sumados.end()) {
            /* Si no existe el elemento lo creamos con el valor de "total" */
            sumados.insert(std::pair<long, double>(actual->nit, actual->total));
        } else {
            /* En caso contrario sumamos al valor anterior el total actual */
            buscaSumados->second += actual->total;
        }
    }

    /* Iteramos por todas las líneas para mostrar el contenido del CSV*/
    for (int i = 0; i < datos_csv.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << i << ".-  " << *datos_csv.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

    /* Ahora iteramos por la suma de nits para mostrar el agregado*/
    for (std::map<long, double>::iterator i = sumados.begin(); i != sumados.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << "nit: " << i->first << ", suma total: " << i->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que yo hago en un caso así es abrir el archivo .csv en un editor de texto, para visualizar como estan estructurador los datos adentro.

Por lo que veo hay 3 tipos de datos:
nit fecha total

**nit** es numero identificador. Aparentemente no supera el numero maximo de un "**unsigned int**"

**fecha** va a ser probablemente un struct utilizando la libreria ctime

**total** con **float** supongo alcanza.

Sigo mirando el archivo o cadena de caracteres y veo que los datos estan separados por comas y probablemente por un caracter especial de new line o retorno de carro /n

por lo que con getline() estaría perfecto para leer linea por linea.

El programa sería algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool leer(const char * nombreArchivo, std::multimap<unsigned int, float>& items); //paso el vector items por referencia para poder mostralo despues en otra funcion
void mostrar(std::multimap<unsigned int, float>& items, std::vector<unsigned int>& duplicados);
void encontrarDuplicados(std::multimap<unsigned int, float>& items, std::vector<unsigned int>& duplicados);

int main()
{
    std::multimap<unsigned int, float> items; //en este mapa guardo los items que leo del archivo
    std::vector<unsigned int> duplicados;

    if (leer("proye.csv", items))
    {
        encontrarDuplicados(items, duplicados);
        mostrar(items, duplicados);
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Presiona Enter para finalizar." << std::endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

bool leer(const char * nombreArchivo, std::multimap<unsigned int, float>& items)
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(nombreArchivo);

    if (!inFile) {
        std::cout << "Error al intentar abrir el archivo: " << nombreArchivo << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::string str;

    std::getline(inFile, str); // la primer linea la leo y la descarto por que se que son los nombres de las columnas

    while (std::getline(inFile, str)) //Leo una nueva linea en el archivo
    {
        std::istringstream ss(str); //transformo la linea en string a stringstream para mas facil separar por comas
        std::vector<std::string> lineasSperadas; //Aqui se almacenan los diferentes datos separaados por coma

        while (ss)
        {
            std::string s;
            if (!getline(ss, s, ','))
                break;
            lineasSperadas.push_back(s);
        }

        items.emplace(std::stoi(lineasSperadas[0]), std::stof(lineasSperadas[2])); //guardo el item en el mapa
    }

    inFile.close();

    return true;
}

void mostrar(std::multimap<unsigned int, float>& items, std::vector<unsigned int>& duplicados)
{
    std::cout << "NIT" << "     " << "Total" << std::endl; //Muestro los titulos

    for (auto item : items)
        std::cout << item.first << "    " << item.second << std::endl; // recorro el vector de items y los muestro en consola


    //Aqui muestro los duplicados tambien utilizando equal_range
    typedef std::multimap<unsigned int, float>::iterator MMAPIterator;
    std::pair<MMAPIterator, MMAPIterator> result;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duplicados" << std::endl; //Muestro los titulos
    std::cout << "NIT" << "     " << "Total" << std::endl; //Muestro los titulos
    for (auto d : duplicados)
    {
        result = items.equal_range(d);
        for (MMAPIterator it = result.first; it != result.second; it++)
        {
            std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
        }
    }   
}

void encontrarDuplicados(std::multimap<unsigned int, float>& items, std::vector<unsigned int>& duplicados)
{
    //Aqui utilizo el equal_range
    typedef std::multimap<unsigned int, float>::iterator MMAPIterator;
    std::pair<MMAPIterator, MMAPIterator> result;

    for (auto item : items)
    {
        result = items.equal_range(item.first);

        int count = std::distance(result.first, result.second);

        if (count > 1)
        {
            for (MMAPIterator it = result.first; it != result.second; it++)
            {
                bool found = false;
                for (auto d : duplicados)
                {
                    if (d == it->first) //aqui me aseguro de solo guardar un NIT
                        found = true;
                }
                if (!found)
                    duplicados.push_back(it->first);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Con eso puedes leer el archivo y espero sirva para que aprendas como se hace. Tal vez no sea perfecto y tenga errores. No lo tomes como correcto.

Si tienes que realizar calculos con las fechas pues te dejo a tu cargo utilizar la libreria ctime y leer las fechas del archivo y transformarlas a una variable ctime para poder calcular diferencias entre fechas. Puede haber otras librerias menos complicadas que ctime.

Para realizar los calculos espero te des cuenta que te faltaba separar los datos y transformarlos para realizar las operaciones matematicas correspondientes. Con el struct que agregué puedes acceder a los datos individualmente y sumarlos, etc ya que cada uno es int o float.

Un saludo espero sea de ayuda.

Editado1: Agregué el map para encontrar duplicados. Espero no se enojen conmigo no estoy seguro de si te ayudo o te lo doy en bandeja XD. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda martin, enserio que me es muchisima ayuda

Comment: fijate que la fecha no es importante
en el archivo que me dieron , tengo 1000 datos de nit con un valor
varios de esos nit estan repetidos pero con otro valor , como podria sumar esos valores que se encontro en un nit repetido

Comment: Si ese es el caso lo mejor seria usar en lugar de un vector un multimap
#include <map>
std::multimap<unsigned int, float> items;
en el primer campo almacenas los NIT y en el segundo el total.

luego con un std::equal_range obtienes los mismos nit.
https://thispointer.com/finding-all-values-for-a-key-in-multimap-using-equals_range-example/

Comment: perdona, el link se encuentra en ingles pero creo que se entiende si lees el codigo.

Comment: Gracias enserio Martin , ahora reviso los errores del codigo

Comment: podrias ayudandome viendo esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/339474/162891

Comment: Ya lo leí, bueno pues, creo que deberías leer el código que te pasé y tratar de entenderlo. ya tienes los duplicados no queda más que sumar. Creo que sumar no es tan dificil no? trata de ir paso a paso con el debugger y mira los valores de las variables para entender un poco la lógica.

Comment: Gracias eso hare entonces , admiro tu conocimiento Martin

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución, @Martin , aunque creo que si lo que quiere es obtener un listado de nits y su total, sumando el valor de los repetidos, no es necesario hacer una búsqueda de nits repetidos para mostrarlos, simplemente se debería almacenar el valor agregado.

Comment: Ya lo creo @OscarGarcia Solo intentaba orientarlo un poco. Sobre como manejar los datos, almacenarlos en algún lugar, accederlos más tarde. Claro que el programa es deficiente y sería poco performante con un millon de NITS. Ten en cuenta que el fue editando la pregunta, supuse que como no almacenaba la información ni la transformaba a int o float para hacer cálculos necesitaba saber eso. Supuse que desde alli el podría darse cuenta de como hacerlo.