# Necesito ir acumulando los totales de compra por NIT de un archivo csv

Tags: c++

Al final, se deberá imprimir en pantalla los

**totales acumulados por NIT**

**la sumatoria de totales por NIT**

**la media**

**el valor mínimo y máximo,**

**la cuenta de NITs**

En este codigo ya tengo separados los nit y totales del, el problema es que en el archivo hay varios nit que se repiten y otros que no se repiten cada nit tiene un valor y el valor de los nit que se repiten se tiene que ir acumulando en uno solo de manera que en la salida cada nit contenga el valor correspondiente sin repetidos

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

 vector<int> numero1;
 vector<int> numero2;
 vector<int> A;
 vector<int> B;
 vector<int> C;
 // std::vector<std::string> fechas;

 int CANTIDAD = 0;
 int NUMERO1=0;
 int NUMERO2=0;
 int a=0;
 int b=0;
 int c=0;

    char linea[1024];
    FILE *fich = fopen("proye.csv", "r");

    while(fgets(linea, 1024, (FILE*) fich)) {

     sscanf(linea, "%d,%d/%d/%d,%i", &NUMERO1, &a,&b,&c, &NUMERO2);
     // fflush(stdin);

     numero1.push_back(NUMERO1);
     numero2.push_back(NUMERO2);

    }



for (int i = 0; i < 1000 ; ++i)
{
    // std::cout << numero1[i] << ", " << std::endl;
    printf(" %d    %d \n",numero1[i], numero2[i]  );
    CANTIDAD++;
}
    cout << "Cantidad de lineas: " << CANTIDAD << endl;
    fclose(fich);
}
```

esta es mi salida 
si se pueden dar cuenta hay nits repetidos 
[image: los datos que tengo que operar]

asi deberia de ser mi salida

[image: lo que esta en la imagen deberia de ser mi salida]

Comment: Por favor, **no dupliques** preguntas. Si la anterior no quedó resuelta, comentalo al autor de la respuesta. Si es una pregunta distinta, **diferenciala** claramente de la anterior. ¿ Te has pasado por el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) ? ¿ Y por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De todas formas te digo: presta atención a los tipos de datos que utilizas: por ej.

```
vector<int> numero1;
vector<int> numero2;
vector<int> A;
vector<int> B;
vector<int> C;
```

Estás utilizando int y los NIT podrian superar el [numero maximo de un int](http://ejercicioscpp.blogspot.com/2012/09/tipos-de-datos-en-c.html): 2147483647 podrias utilizar unsigned int cuyo número máximo es 4294967295 y ningún NIT es negativo.

revisa [aqui](http://ejercicioscpp.blogspot.com/2012/09/tipos-de-datos-en-c.html) para saber más.

También presta atención al total. es un número con coma, para esos debes usar float o double que manejan números decimales. Si lo lees del archivo y lo muestras en pantalla lo ves bien pero si lo almacenas en una variable de tipo int lo que esté después de la coma queda truncado.

Bueno pues revisa la otra respuesta y espero te ayude

Comment: Claro que me sirvio amigo, aprecio mucho tu ayuda