# Estoy programando en C++ alguien me podria decir como le puedo hacer para que mis cantidades salgan asi

Tags: c++

[image: imagen salida]

como le puedo hacer para que mis cantidades tengan la coma de centena, mil, millar tambien con resultados con punto decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es únicamente visual los números que se están mostrando, son Strings.
Para convertir números a Strings y además tener ese formato, te recomiendo esta función en la cual tú le pasarás los números que quieres convertir, y te devolverá la cantidad divida por comas cada 3 dígitos en String.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> //Necesitas esta librería, es para Stringstream

using namespace std;
string separarDigitos(double);  

int main(){
    double numero = 5426987.96;
    cout<<"Numero: "<< separarDigitos(numero);
    return 0;
}

string separarDigitos(double numero){
    stringstream flujo;
    flujo<<fixed<<numero;
    string numeroString = flujo.str();
    string numeroEditado;
    if (numeroString.find(".") != string::npos){
        numeroEditado = numeroString.substr(numeroString.find("."), 3);
        numeroString = numeroString.substr(0, numeroString.find("."));
    }
    int c = 0;
    for(int i=numeroString.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        if (c % 3 == 0 && c != 0) {
            numeroEditado = "," + numeroEditado;
        }
        c++;
        numeroEditado = numeroString[i] + numeroEditado;
    }
    return numeroEditado;
}
```

La entrada en este caso es 5426987.96, la salida será: Número: 5,426,987.96

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

> como le puedo hacer para que mis cantidades tengan la coma de centena, mil, millar tambien con resultados con punto decimal

Por supuesto una vía es hacerlo a mano... convertir el número a cadena y luego insertar una coma cada tres dígitos enteros... pero es una solución un tanto chapucera.

Se puede resolver de forma un poco más *elegante* usando locales.

Lo primero es crear nuestro propio local:

```
#include <locale>

struct custom_locale : std::numpunct<char> {
    char_type do_thousands_sep() const override { return ','; } // Separador de miles
    char_type do_decimal_point() const override { return '.'; } // Separador decimal
    string_type do_grouping() const override { return "\3"; }   // Dígitos entre cada separador de miles
};
```

Y ahora le inyectamos nuestra configuración a `cout`:

```
#include <iostream>

custom_locale my_locale;
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), &my_locale));
```

Y ya podemos hacer la prueba:

```
std::cout << 12345.67; // Salida: 12,345.7
```

Bueno, queda como queríamos... más o menos... ahora hay que configurar la salida para que los números tengan la cantidad de decimales que esperamos.

Para solucionar este problema podemos recurrir a la librería `iomanip`:

```
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 12345.67 << '\n' << 1234.5;
```

Ahora la salida será la siguiente:

```
12,345.67
1,234.50
```

Nos vamos acercando pero aún nos queda alinear ambos números... no hay problema:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
          << std::setw(10) << 12345.67 << '\n'
          << std::setw(10) << 1234.5;
```

Ahora la salida que obtendremos será la siguiente:

```
 12,345.67
  1,234.50
```

Todo junto quedaría así:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct custom_locale : std::numpunct<char> {
    char_type do_thousands_sep() const override { return ','; }
    char_type do_decimal_point() const override { return '.'; }
    string_type do_grouping() const override { return "\3"; }
};

int main()
{
    custom_locale my_locale;
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), &my_locale));
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
              << std::setw(10) << 12345.67 << '\n'
              << std::setw(10) << 1234.5;
}
```

Comment: graciaas, como podria agregarselo a este codigo disculpa, para que las cantidades salgan asi como tu dices https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/339474/162891

Comment: @CristhianAlexanderCuxumAgui Tienes que dejar de usar printf y reemplazarlo por cout

Comment: ¿y como le podría hacer si quisiera hacer separaciones con coma cada que aparezca un numero impar? por ejemplo 5-4269-87. Necesito ayuda por favoor

Comment: @NPE eso tendrías que programarlo a mano. Los usos de locale no tienen en cuenta si los dígitos son pares o impares